# Does downloading g++ to windows guarantee you will compile Unix projects successfully?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, unix

So here is the link : 
http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html

My Unix project uses this :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curses.h>
```

Is it a guarantee? I heard that you can compile the Unix projects using g++ (I have makefile too). I am only familiar about Windows and I don't know anything about Linux and Mac.

Comment: The short answer is, no. If a Linux C++ program uses a particular library, such as ncurses, that library must, obviously, be installed in order to be able to compile code that uses it. `curses.h` is the ncurses library, which does not come with gcc.

Comment: You could always just make a virtual machine and run your code in that.

Comment: You want Cygwin.  http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guarantee. I'm close to say: "impossible, except for very simple code".
Simple code: calculations, input/output to the console, simple file operations.
Not simple code: anything you ask the OS to do, specially related to windows and messages. And special OS-dependant headers.

g++ is the compiler from GNU. Its main use is in Linux. There are a few (but popular) "adaptations" in order to use it in Windows: cygwin, MinGW, etc.

Comment: Even "simple code" wouldn't work. Console I/O requires interaction with the OS. Windows won't even recognize the format of executables from a Linux or Mac system -- not any program compiled with g++, and not g++ itself. You could compile an empty program `int main(){}` on Linux, copy the executable to Windows, and Windows won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Yes, an executable will NOT work in other OS.
And Yes, simple C++ code can be easely *compiled* again in other OS and will work there. Console I/O code, using cin/cout will work in any OS.